# Why does where clause not work in my sql query?

Tags: mysql

In the below code if I replace having clause with where clause I get a 1054 error saying unknown column tsal in where clause. Why? Also pls enlighten me on cases specifically where I have to use having and where I have to use where clause.

```
select employee_id,salary*months as tsal1
from Employee as h
having tsal1=(select max(e.tsal) as metsal
from (select employee_id,salary*months as tsal
from Employee) as e)
```

Comment: One of the key reasons for the inability to use that alias in the `where` clause is that SQL is **not** executed in the same sequence that you write the query. The `from` and `where` clauses are evaluated **before** the `select` clause.  I can recommend this excellent blog on the topic: [A Beginner’s Guide to the True Order of SQL Operations](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/)

Answer (score 0):

MySql does [not allow](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html) you to refer to an alias (defined in the `select` clause) from within a `where` clause.

To work around this, just repeat the expression for that alias:

```
select employee_id, salary*months as tsal1
from   Employee as h
where salary*months=(select max(e.tsal) as metsal
                     from   (select employee_id,salary*months as tsal
                             from   Employee) as e)
```

NB: There should be no need for having two inner sub queries. You can simplify to:

```
select employee_id, salary*months as tsal1
from   Employee as h
where  salary*months=(select max(salary*months) from Employee)
```